# WHY to say "a secret prayer" to zip the dress and what does it mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, culture

I am not sure if I get this right : "a secret prayer" means "she is a little fat so that she prays the zip could go up"?? (a little fat is a fact based in the novel). And I neither get the meaning of "a frugal generation" in the sentence, does it mean she does not have enough money when she made the dress?

Why is it a "result" dress??, the author put the " " on the word "result" to emphasize , but I have no idea at all what it looks like??

Here is the sentence:

> ……and instead put on my fourth option, a vintage dress in dark-red satin. It was made for **a more frugal generation** and I always had to say
>   **a secret prayer** that the zip would make it up past my waist, but it gave me the outline of a 1950s starlet, and it was **a ‘results’
>   dress**, one of those outfits you couldn’t help but feel good in.

The context is :

The girl is going to a concert and she is trying on the fourth dress, and actually it turns out great on her later as the viewers approve her choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

She secretly prayed that the zip would go all the way to the top, due to her waist being possibly slightly too large for the dress. The dress was made (not by her) for a generation previous to that of the wearer, perhaps her parents' generation or earlier still, and that generation spent less money on food of the fattening type. Thus people were thinner on average.  A "results" dress (plural in the text) is a dress that gets [desired] results, e.g. favourable attention, admiration, requests to dance, etc.

She did not necessarily actually pray in a religious sense; she probably just hoped that the zip would go up. To be frugal is to be sparing or economical with money or food. To "get results" is to succeed.

Comment: yes! then I get it. I have mistaken it for her  own making dress. now I grasp in this sentence that 'a frugal generation' referring to someone thinner  or the dress cut  for thinner people.

Comment: A frugal generation means people of a former time who did not spend so much money on cakes, fatty food, etc, as people do now.

Comment: seriously?? is it a common understanding, or just in this sentence? not because they were living in a time when material wealth is less than now? so that they have to be carful with money use.

Comment: "Frugal" doesn't mean "poor", it means "careful with resources". So yes, it is implying that people were more careful how they spent their money.

Comment: Of course, a generation may well be frugal because there isn't a lot to go around :)

Comment: so, here in this sentence, just in this context, "a frugal generation" does not specifically or only mean" they are frugal on fatten food",but a general sense of "be frugal with all anything if needed." am I right or close to right?

Comment: Depending on when this story was written, the 'frugal generation' could be one that rationed food as in the UK during and after World War II. Some types of food were rationed until 1954.

Comment: Pragmatically you're probably right, but I don't think it's in any way asserted or implied by the text itself that the speaker herself was never a member of that "more frugal generation". She might be an octogenarian film star still (just! :) capable of squeezing into the custom-made dress she first wore at her "Coming Out" party as a teenage deb!